# jquery (cheerio) html response table cannot convert to array (for parsing)

Tags: jquery, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am developing a simple node app to scraping html table from a website.

I am using cheerio (jquery in server side). I get the html from website and I select the table as below:

**ADDED DETAILS IN EDIT**

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var app = express();

app.get('/scrape', function (req, res) {


url = 'http://es.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EJKSE/';

request(url, function (error, response, html) {
    if (!error) {

        var $ = cheerio.load(html);


     $('#yfncsumtab .yfnc_tableout1 tr td table tbody').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());

   });

 /* //I also have tried this without success

$('#yfncsumtab .yfnc_tableout1 tr td table tbody').find('tr').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).text());
//Nothing in log, it breaks before
   });


 */
```

But please note above details (console selector is not returning an array of html, only raw html, so I cannot "play" with the data, to scrape it.

The problem, comes here. If I test this jquery selector in the console it returns raw html:

```
<table>...</table>
```

But if I test in another html tables (with its proper ids/classes) from other websites it returns the html as an array:

```
[ <table>...</table> ]
```

In the firs case I neither cannot use .forEach() function to parse the table because is not an array, nor .toArray(), to convert to an array at least.

Is very strange for me... Any help?

This is the url: https://es.finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EJKSE/

Is "https" (I have tried http and https in the url string, but without success.

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to be somewhat more specific and show us how you're using `forEach` etc? As a sidenote Cheerio is not really jQuery. it looks the same but there are subtle differences that can mess things up if you follow jQuery's documentation and not Cheerio's documentation, however what they both have in common is that `forEach` shouldn't be used to iterate over collections, they have their own `.each()` method.

Comment: I have added the code of .forEchar (as far as I concerned cheerio has the same syntax as jQuery).

Comment: But note the detail of the response is not array (I don't understand, is the firs time I see that, I cannot do any parsing with the html).

Comment: Not sure I get it, `$(this).text()` returns a string of the text in the element only?

Comment: $(this).text() does'n returns anything (is undefined).

Comment: $(this).text() does'n returns anything (is undefined).
If I test this selector expresion in the console, it returns html table (but not in an array):
     
       $('#yfncsumtab .yfnc_tableout1 tr td table tbody')

Can anybody explain me why I am not obtaining an array contaning the html table??? That's the reason why I cannot apply .each(), .text() ... I think

Comment: Link's dead at this point, so voting to close. I bet it was added with JS, and Cheerio doesn't execute JS.